# InvocationHandler doesn't see method annotation declared with Retention.RUNTIME policy

Tags: java, reflection

**MyAnnotation** class:

```
package test;

import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyAnnotation {
}
```

**MyClass** class:

```
package test;


import java.lang.reflect.Proxy;


public class MyClass implements MyInterface {

    @Override
    @MyAnnotation
    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("Do something from MyClass");
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var obj = new MyClass();
        var proxy = (MyInterface)Proxy.newProxyInstance(obj.getClass().getClassLoader(),
                                                        obj.getClass().getInterfaces(),
                                                        new MyInvocationHandler(obj));

        proxy.doSomething();
    }
}
```

**MyInterface** class:

```
package test;

public interface MyInterface {
    void doSomething();
}
```

**MyInvocationHandler** class:

```
package test;

import java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class MyInvocationHandler implements InvocationHandler {

    private final MyClass origin;


    public MyInvocationHandler(MyClass origin) {
        this.origin = origin;
    }


    @Override public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(method.getAnnotations()));
        method.invoke(origin, args);
        return proxy;
    }
}
```

In the `invoke` method in `MyInvocationHandler` the print shows empty array of annotations, although I have annotated `MyClass.doSomething()` method with `@MyAnnotation`:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(method.getAnnotations()));
```

If I put the annotation in `MyInterface.doSomething()` it is seen and printed:

```
public interface MyInterface {
    @MyAnnotation
    void doSomething();
}
```

Why is that and how can I create an invocation handler that is able to see and check for `method` annotations?

Comment: Why do you think the proxy should extend your class? Proxies extend `java.lang.reflect.Proxy`. There is simply no relationship between `MyClass` and your proxy.

Comment: The proxy implements `MyInterface` and gets a `Method` object representing the method `doSomething()` declared in `MyInterface`. There is no reason why it should see an annotation that this method doesn’t have.